# How do I limit file size for UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the following code:

```
func addAttachmentUtil() {
    print("file attacher")
    let file = UIImagePickerController()
    file.delegate = self

    file.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    file.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
    file.videoMaximumDuration = 5.0

    file.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(file, animated: true)
    {
    }
}
```

However I also want to limit the file on the basis of size (which would be 25 MB). I am not able to understand how to do this? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit what’s displayed or prevent the user from choosing a bigger video. After the user chooses, you can look at the file and decide to do nothing with it.

Comment: Does choosing a larger video means it will be imported into the memory also?

Comment: No. Videos are never held in memory.

Comment: @EnrikQaz for this you have to find some SDK to provide this kind of functionality(If exist).